# ¿Como se asignan internamente los valores de los slices en python3?

Tags: python-3.x, slice

Cuando se omiten los valores de los slices, estos toman un valor por defecto pero este valor no es una **constante** si no mas bien una **variable**, por ejemplo:

```py
string = 'word'
print(string[::1]) """Recorro el {string} caracter por caracter de izquierda a derecha pero 
                   omitiendo el primer y segundo valor dentro de los slices"""
'word'
print(string[::1] == string[0:len(string):1]) """Aqui compruebo que los dos valores 
                                              omitidos que se asignan por defecto son 0 y 
                                              {len(string)} (4 para este caso)"""
True
```

Ahora bien, recorriendo el string de derecha a izquierda, estos valores que se omiten varian y es por eso que digo que no son **constantes** si no **variables**:

```
print(string[::-1])
'drow'
print(string[::-1] == string[-1::-1]) """Dedusco que el primer valor que se asigna por 
                                      defecto es -1 y este varia dependiendo si el tercero
                                      es positivo o negativo"""
True
```

Resulta que el segundo valor que se asigna por defecto es una **incognita** para mi, ya que no es -1, 0 o 1:

```
print(string[-1::-1])
'drow'
print(string[-1:-1:-1])
'' """Retorna una cadena vacia puesto que inicia en -1 (que es el ultimo caracter: 'd')
   y termina en el ultimo caracter (d) sin incluirlo """
print(string[-1:0:-1)])
'dro' """Retorna 'dro' por que inicia en -1 (que es el ultimo caracter: 'd') y termina en  
      0 (que es el primer caracter: 'w') pero sin incluirlo ya que el 
      segundo valor dentro del slice no es inclusivo"""
print(string[-1:1:-1])
'ro'
```

Entonces:
¿Cual es el segundo valor que python3 asigna dentro del slice? o ¿como funciona internamente esta asignacion?

Comment: En una búsqueda rápida no encontré alguna referencia a documentación oficial pero con una prueba rápida si pones `-len(string)-1` devuelve `drow`. Por lo que quedaría `string[-1:-len(string)-1:-1]`. Saliendo del trabajo si alguien no ha dado una respuesta completa buscaré en la documentación.

Comment: Interesante, gracias por el comentario.

Comment: Aaaaa viejo claro, asi como se puede asumir (cuando los pasos del slice son positivos) que se ira hasta el caracter de posicion`4` del string sin incluirlo (al igual ni existe), asi tambien se puede asumir (cuando los pasos del slice son negativos) que ira hasta el caracter de posicion `-5` que tampoco existe pero eso hace que si se incluya el caracter de posicion  `-4` que a su vez es el mismo caracter cuya posicion es `0`.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato gracias por hacerme ver lo que yo ignoraba.